# Log4Net with Unity: Where do appender files get saved?

Tags: unity-game-engine, log4net, log4net-appender

I can't seem to save my file into the `Logs` directory just under the project directory. The one that every Unity comes with by default.

Sample code

```
                var fileAppender = new FileAppender
                {
                    AppendToFile = false,
                    File = @$"Logs\Basic_{id}.txt",
                    Layout = patternLayout,
                };
                fileAppender.ActivateOptions();

                BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);
```

My Unity project structure is the normal structure including the `Logs` directory that unity provides. This code is located in the some other folder(deep into the project base dir).

And yes I have hunted down that `Logs` directory all the way from where the code originates up until my system base directory on Linux Ubuntu. Which is called 'Home'.

Comment: Have you checked for exceptions? Usually you can't write to anything within the installation folder of the application .. try to rather write into [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)

Comment: `Logs\Basic_{id}.txt` is not a valid file path in Linux (or any other OS I know) ... a) Linux (Unix) uses forward `/` as path separator and b) you can't just start with `Logs` and expect the OS to find that folder. A relative path would rather look like e.g. `./Logs/filename` ... but as said try to rather use `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, $"Basic_{id}.txt")` this makes sure the correct path separator is used depending on the executing OS and the location can be found in the link above